# cakephp secure keyword like login method

Tags: security, cakephp, methods, authentication, keyword

I want to achieve something like below scenario mention in CakePHP 1.3.8 a latest version:

- Ask for `Username / Password` or directly ask for `Secret Keyword`
- If correct, ask for `Secret Keyword`
- If correct, access more `details of website`
- If wrong, `don't allow` any further access

There is `Auth` component into CakePHP for authentication like `username/password` however I want to implement this extra step of `Secret Keyword` to access information which should be stored in somefile, `encrypted way` or some other better way you suggest in a `single computer` usage only.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically turn off `autoRedirect` so I can do extra stuff in my `login` method. I typically don't do *this* much work, but you can probably repurpose accordingly by, after authentication is complete/successful. It's not a complete answer, nor is the following a complete code snippet for your requirement, but it may be enough to get you started.

```
/** Logging in and authenticated */
if ( !empty( $this->data ) && $this->Auth->user() ) {
  $this->User->id = $this->Auth->user( 'id' );
  $this->set_user_type();
  $this->User->saveField( 'last_login', date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) );

  if( $this->User->has_building( $this->Auth->User('id') ) ) {
    $this->redirect( array( 'controller' => 'buildings', 'action' => 'incentives' ) );
  }
  else {
    $this->redirect( $this->Auth->redirect() );
  }
}
```

This is a snippet from one of my own projects. In your case, you might look for a secret key value next. If that doesn't exist, drop into a view to retrieve that and submit back to this same method. On the second pass, if the user is authenticated and the secret key is passed and exists, then redirect as required. If the secret key is wrong, then de-authenticate the user and redirect.

Like I said, not a complete answer and a very simple look at a hard problem, but hopefully it helps you get started.